# How to print these elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, name, place,loc,id):
        self.name = name
        self.place = place
        self.loc=loc
        self.id=id

my_list = []
with open("dat.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
        # line is each line in the file
        # let's pretend our file structure is "NAME PLACE"
        entry = line.strip().split(" ", 5) # data[0] = name, data[1] = place
        my_list.append(Data(entry[0],entry[1],entry[2],entry[3]))
```

My file contains 100 lines and each line has 4 columns.

How do I print all the data?

Comment: class Data:
    def __init__(self, name, place,loc,id):
        self.name = name
        self.place = place
        self.loc=loc
        self.id=id
        


my_list = []
with open("dat.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
        # line is each line in the file
        # let's pretend our file structure is "NAME PLACE"
        entry = line.strip().split(" ", 5) # data[0] = name, data[1] = place
        my_list.append(Data(entry[0],entry[1],entry[2],entry[3]))

Comment: Can you format you code?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Why don't you just `print my_list`?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, you need something like that

```
for s in my_list:
    print s.name,s.place,s.id, s.loc
```

Or like that

```
for s in my_list:
    print "{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(s.name,s.place,s.loc) # or smth like that
```